# How to convert YUY2 to JPEG without reading/writing files (C++)?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, jpeg, rgb

I have a single frame (YUY2) from webcam in `LPVIDEOHDR` structure captured with vfw32 (`capGrabFrame(...)` and `CALLBACK` on it). I need to get from `VHDR->lpData` another buffer (char*, LPBYTE... doesn't matter) with compressed JPEG. In all examples I saw in web (GDI+, libjpeg) this conversion is performed with reading/writing files...

**So how to convert YUY2 to JPEG in buffer?**

*PS: if RGB needed, I have YUY2 to RGB algorithm*

Comment: Does this YUY2 to RGB algorithm work in buffer ?

Comment: Yes, it works, but image is flipped verticaly. But its not a problem to flip it

Comment: Maybe this: http://supercomputingblog.com/optimization/in-memory-image-compression-tutorial/

Comment: @SvenNilsson, it's something new! Thanks, I'll try it...

Comment: @SvenNilsson, GREAT THANKS! I did it - 6 Kb jpeg from 150 Kb RGB! No libraries, no cross-compiling for MinGW... just an algorithm! The best solution! Thank You very much!

Comment: You are welcome